# Finding least positive integer $n$

Tags: number-theory

Question is:

> find the least positive integer $n$ such that $$274| n^{4}+1$$

Can you give some hint? I know how to prove the existence of such $n$, but don't know how to actually solve it...

Answer (score 1):

For $n=41$ we have $n^4+1=41^4+1=2\cdot 137\cdot 10313$. It is not difficult to see that there is no smaller $n$ with $274=2\cdot 137\mid n^4+1$. First, $n$ has to be odd. Then it is enough to solve the congruence $n^4+1\equiv 0 \bmod 137$.